# How to write a Typescript definition file for a library that puts methods on the global namespace (window)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, global, typescript-typings

I am building an application in Typescript which relies on the [P5.js library](http://p5js.org/reference/).

`P5.js` puts a lot of functions on the global namespace so they can be called in your webapp by just saying things like `draw()`, and `ellipse(x, y, w, l)` etc...

I am working in Webstorm and I want Webstorm to be able to perform its static analysis for me, so I have been adding the function names of P5.js to a `p5.d.ts` file ([there is no](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) p5.js Typescript definition file published yet), like:

```
declare var setup: () => void;
declare var draw: () => void;
declare var background: (color: number) => void;
declare var stroke: (r: number, g: number, b: number) => void;
...
```

However this is not ideal.

#1: These functions actually do return something - a P5 Object - which contains all these methods,  though it's usually not used.

#2: I am still calling these methods throughout my application without any prefix or anything. This makes it a bit ambiguous as to where these functions are actually from.

There are more issues as well...

Can anyone offer some pointers on how to go about creating a `.d.ts` for a library like P5.js?

Comment: Note that p5js does have a feature request for type definition files https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more natural to write these as functions. You can also declare an interface type to represent the common return type (I'm assuming they have it set up as a "chaining" API?)

```
declare function stroke(r: number, g: number, b: number): P5;
declare function background(color: number): P5;

interface P5 {
  stroke(r: number, g: number, b: number): P5;
  background(color: number): P5;
}
```

Unfortunately in TypeScript there isn't a way to say "Make this part of the global scope at the same time", so you'll have to duplicate these definitions.

Regarding #2, well, that's P5's problem? I would see if the P5 documentation provides for a smarter way to invoke the functions. Putting a bunch of stuff in the global scope isn't a common pattern for JS libraries anymore so there's probably some other way to do it.

#### Update

Yes apparently [there is another way to use P5.js functions without polluting the global namespace](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#instantiation--namespace).

Comment: If you are putting the functions in the interface, do you also have to `declare` them?